# Visual Studio warning: “Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read”

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday I made some changes for my solution such as renamed it and moved to a different location in TFS 2013 server.

Today I received the message

> “One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
>   Please see the Output Window for details”

when opening a solution in Visual Studio:

Unfortunatley the details in the output window were not very helpful:

> Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read

I only have one project in the solution. Here is the solution file.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GenericIVR",  "OutboundGeneric\GenericIVR.csproj", "{3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 1
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://tfs01:8080/tfs/software%20repository
        SccProjectUniqueName0 = OutboundGeneric\\GenericIVR.csproj
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        AnotherDebug|Any CPU = AnotherDebug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.AnotherDebug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = AnotherDebug|Any CPU
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.AnotherDebug|Any CPU.Build.0 = AnotherDebug|Any CPU
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
 EndGlobalSection
 GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
 EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution section with the following lines after "SccTeamFoundationServer":

```
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = OutboundGeneric\\GenericIVR.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = GenericIVR
    SccLocalPath1 = GenericIVR
```

Don't ask me why that SccLocalPath0 should be present, but I have seen it in the older VS version too.

Comment: Just wonder why did you use SccProjectName1 rather than SccProjectName0? There is only one project, I think that it is a 0 base index.

Comment: What I did is create a blank solution file and then I added an project to it. This is how VS creates the soultion file (by default). I tried to remove the "SccLocalPath0 = ." (and make it SccProjectName0, SccLocalPath0 etc) but then it throws the error "Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read."

Answer (score 5):

Following on from the suggestion above, I found that in my case the solution file had an incorrect number of SccNumberOfProjects configured. Somehow I had managed to get 15, a quick count and correction of the number of projects contained in the solution fixed it for me.

```
Global  
   GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
     SccNumberOfProjects = 13
     SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
```

Comment: +1 for adding this as an answer (too bad one can't select two answers as "the answer").  This particular one seems to be the answer that I was looking for.  Long story short, the solution I'm working on is being trimmed down and several projects were removed.  The `SccNumberOfProjects = <int>` for me was set to `28` but a quick count of the projects was `20`.  I suspect something was missed in a merge from main.

Comment: This happened for me as well as a result of a bad merge in TFVC.  If your solution file was recently merged, this could easily be the problem

Answer (score 4):

I also had a similar problem, in my case I had two GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution sections in my sln. I **manually removed the content of the section** (and deleted the 2nd entirely). Then I opened my solution and got an error 'solution not under source control'. Then I Added it to source control again via **Add to Source Control**. Then I saved everything and the section was restored.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what caused this for me, but my solution was to delete everything between "Global" and "EndGlobal" and then open the solution. It rebuilt the solution file and works fine. Comparing the old and new, it seems probable that there was extraneous info within GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution

Before:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|Default = Debug|Default
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    Release|Default = Release|Default
EndGlobalSection
```

After

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to anhoppe, but with a couple of differences.

I had a situation where a merge of a .sln file had resulted in 2 separate GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) sections, the first had the incorrect number of projects in it, the second had the correct number.

I initially deleted the first GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) and left the second one in place. This didn't work and I still saw the error...

> Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be
>   read

So, I undid this change and then deleted just the second GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl), saved and re-opened the solution. This did the job and I just had to re-add the couple of projects that had been taken out of source control.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the issue in VS2015 by editing the `.sln` file...

Every entry in

> GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution sections

needed to have both entries for each configuration

```
{3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{3B46A2C8-B9FF-48F3-978D-CF27B1EC917D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
```

When

> solution could not be read

occurred, only the `ActiveCfg` entry was present. Added the `Build.0` entry where it was omitted and

> solution could not be read

was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced same issue but found that SccNumberOfProjects = 11 where i have only 10 projects in my solution, so i have changed 10 insteadof 11, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS2017.

I tried to delete everything between "Global" and "EndGlobal" as the answer in this post. It works.
Then I find the reason why it works: it makes VS delete all "Release" configuration in all .csproj.

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```

I guess the problem in my case was caused by using "Release" configuration to build then went back to “Debug” configuration to code & debug.